# Neural Engine iPhone/iPad Programming

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gpu

Google has not helped me at all with the question of how to program this "Neural Engine" on the latest iOS devices, and especially what happens if a NE app gets downloaded on older devices without the NE. I had to "read between the lines" to conclude that you have to use Core ML 2 and leave iOS to execute your code in the best hardware, best way it knows how. Which leaves you exposed to not particularly optimized code on the NE, and perhaps overstretching the devices without NE. I was also left with the impression that there is no middle ground by using the Metal engine, but really I don't even know right now what gave me that impression. Has anyone figured out which is which, which is the definitive way to exploit the NE and if it is wiser to perhaps disallow the older devices, or will the NE "emulation" always work?

Comment: I am wondering if this might better be asked on an actual Apple developer discussion board staffed by Apple engineers who are there to help devs who need specific target info on things like this. Just wondering...

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is best practice to find (buy, save, beg, borrow, testflight enroll) the oldest, slowest iOS device(s) you choose to allow under your OS Deployment Target Xcode setting and the Required Device Capabilities as specified in the app's plist.  Then you can benchmark your code, and make a judgement call as to whether this meets your product's performance goals, or not.  Your potential customer's possible exposure to varying performance levels then becomes a business decision.

This is true for any ML, GPU/Metal, or numerically CPU intensive app (not just ML 2 or NE related).